# AJAX путает параметр и глобальную переменную (одноимённые)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global-variables

В самом начале файла .js объявляю переменную:

```
var CurrentMonth = 0;
```

После имеется событие клика:

```
$(".calendar .sliderLeft").click(function() {
    SlideCalendar(type, 'left', CurrentMonth);
    return false;
});
```

Которое вызывает AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {type : type, NextPrevMouth : NextPrevMouth, CurrentMonth : CurrentMonth},....
```

А он в свою очередь возвращает:

```
success: function(data) {
CurrentMonth = data.CurrentMonth;
}
```

И при следующем клике в AJAX подставляет всё равно значение CurrentMonth = 0, а не значение вернувшееся от AJAX success.

Comment: не верю!

ЗЫ: глобальной переменной var не нужен.

Comment: вы второй клик точно после того как success выполнится делаете ?